# Visual Studio External references not working on published website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have created a web project that works fine when published and when debugging inside Visual Studio. When I add an external reference via the reference manager, it adds it properly and runs within Visual Studio to the internal IIS Express. When I publish the website to my server, the external apps do not work and it looks as though they are not even available.

What am I missing to get these Interop dll's to be seen in the web server?

There must be some 'hook' to connect to these dll's that is used when run locally that doesn't exist when deployed. In a nutshell, this is an API that I am trying to deploy to the server where the app is installed and running. The API functions normally when run locally within VS, but does not work when I deploy it to the IIS website on the same server. The IIS website has full permissions, which is not an issue because this site is only run on an internal network and not to the web.

UPDATE:
Digging deeper in the mystery I suspect it has something to do with The way the COM interops, or API's, are used. I have set the project properties to 'Generate COM interop' and have the API reference properties set to Isolated=false and Embed Interop Type=True. I have also set the ComVisible=true for the entire project. There are no build errors. There are no errors in the .net or IIS logs that I can see. I have set full permissions to all the applicable folders. So, what am I missing?

I guess I have the community stumped on this one. I am going to try to change to a late bound caller and see if that helps.

For those interested it seems the issue was with the DCOM permissions on the server. Still doesn't work, but at least the server sees the API now, just has COM Exception errors but that is way beyond my ability. There is no source code or vendor support for the API. Kind of makes me mad since I paid for the API and when I ask for assistance they say there is no support available.

Comment: As a side note. These are COM references.

Comment: can you be more specific about these dlls?

Comment: One of the dll's is a common one, interop.VBA The others are vendor specific. The DLL's were pulled from the executable that was added into the Reference manager. This COM reference is an API which send calls to the program running on the local machine. When the calls are made locally in VS they work, but when I deploy the web project to the same server into IIS, the COM no longer functions.

Comment: what exactly happens on the published web site that tells you that the referenced dlls are not working?

Comment: the website hangs and does not invoke the vendor app. When I run locally withing VS, it works.

Comment: When I said 'hang' I mean at the point that it uses the API, the website just hangs. If I comment out the Interop's, the site works fine. So it's just as though the browser does not know what to do when it hits the API. IE hangs. Firefox responds with 'The page isn't redirecting properly'

Comment: you need to find out what exactly is going wrong. Do you having any error logging in your application? have you checked the Windows event logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referencing local external assemblies, then add them as part of the solution (say in a ThirdPartyAssemblies folder), and then set each DLL to "Copy Always" under Properties.

That should make sure that your assemblies are copied to your bin on build, and they'll be visible on your web server.

Comment: That did not work. The dll's do copy now to the bin folder on the web server, but do not function. When the calls are made, it should invoke a program on the server. I installed VS and the project on the server, ran it locally and it worked fine. If I publish it to the local system, it does not work.

Comment: Do I need to register these DLL's in the bin folder?

Comment: You don't need to register COM dlls in the bin folder as they don't need a special folder but you may very well need to register them. The problem with testing in VS is you are generally running with more permissions than an average internet guest account is allowed. Most web server's aren't configured to be calling COM components or other resources without you elevating those permissions or applying them to the dlls and the resources they need.

Comment: What do you mean you don't need to register COM dll's, but I may need to register them? When I try to register these dll's I get error stating the entry point was not found.

Comment: I gave full permissions to the site and still no go